# How to get a Console application to talk to itself by simulating user input - Console.WriteLine() and Console.Readline()?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application built (like a terminal) where user is asked for their input.

Now I want to extend this application by completely automating it. Instead of the user having to type "1", "2", "3" - the console application would end up simulating the user input instead:

- types "1"
- waits 1 second
- types "2"
- waits 1 second
- types "3"

Here is some oversimplified code:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("hello");
Console.WriteLine("user wrote to me: " + userInput); // This should output "user wrote to me: hello"
```

The problem is that basically the thread stops on `Console.Readline()` and waits for input. How can I avoid that?

Creating a separate thread to run `Console.ReadLine()` did not work.

I am aware that this is not the best approach to the problem, but I would like to make as little changes as possible (I do not want to refactor the code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

Console.SetIn(new StringReader(@"hello
more lines
here"));

string userInput;
while ((userInput = Console.ReadLine()) is not null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("user wrote to me: " + userInput);
}
```

Obviously you can use your own custom `TextReader` for more advanced scenarios (for example to insert time delays via `Thread.Sleep` or `Task.Delay`, or to invent values rather than having to hard-code them), and similarly you can use `SetOut` with your own `TextWriter` to intercept output.

Comment: Stream reader may also refer to a file : `FileInfo sourceFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\cities.txt");
    TextReader sourceFileReader = new StreamReader(sourceFile.FullName);
    Console.SetIn(sourceFileReader);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys`. This is a simple code that wait for user input and receive data from the `SimulateUserInput` task:

```cs
using System.Text;
internal class Program {
    private static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        var simulateTask = SimulateUserInput();
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Read: {userInput}");
        await simulateTask;
    }

    public static async Task SimulateUserInput() {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("1");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("2");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("\r\n");

    }
}
```

In order to reference `System.Windows.Forms` from a console application you must modify the console application projcet, specifically the `.csproj` project file, in this way:

- set the `sdk` property of `project` node to `"Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop"`
- add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` tag
- set the target framework to `net7.0-windows`

as in:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>  
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```